# Why is AdMob ad Frequency capping not working?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I set two impressions per minute per user but it doesn't work. Ads keep showing every time.

[image]

on AdMob site they say : A change to frequency capping, such as changing the cap from two to three, can take up to a day to take effect.

But it has been more than FIVE days since I applied change to Frequency capping and it is not working? Here is how I request ads :

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new   AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

I use `setTestDevice` so real ads wont show app because impressions on real ads can get me banned.

Answer (score 3):

Admob puts frequency capping on Real Ads only and not on Test Ads. Try removing your test device and observe real Ads, frequency capping works. I have tried and tested on Emulator and Real device.
Found no docs for reference, this is from my experience.

To Suffice-

- Frequency capping works when Not added as Test Device
- Frequency capping does not work Added as Test Device

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Testing real ads on a test device is not a good advice tho :) Baaaaad traffic

Comment: @alpertign please why is this bad?

Comment: @HasIEluS If you run real ads on an unapproved device with no ID, google will detect it and give your admob account a bad traffic penalty. And they don't even state the reason for it not to be reverse-engineered.